# Moving a file into a folder, only giving a partial string as a destination directory

Tags: shell, directory

Messing around with shell-scripts. Is it possibly to use mv, while only giving a partial name for the destination directory?

Example below:

`find *partial_file_name* -exec mv {} *partial_folder_name* \;`

Comment: If the glob for the destination *directory* is unique, your notation is almost correct.  You can do `find /dir -name '*partial*' -exec mv {} '*partial-directory-name*'`. But this only works if the target directory has a name like `this-is-the-partial-directory-name`  and is the unique expansion of the glob.

Comment: @user6076: You must be pretty brave: If there is more than one match, the matching directories will be moved into the final one and you will end up with a real mess. If i would implement such a feature, I would write a custom `mv` script which  explicitly tests for uniquness, and aborts with an error message instead of creating havoc.